# Unable to connect to AWS RDS through PDO

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, pdo, amazon-ec2

I set up a MySQL RDS instance in AWS. After instantiating the instance I tried to connect it from my EC2's command line and it works with no issue. However, when I try connecting through my PHP code I get erros. Below is the sample code that I tried to test my connectivity.

```
<?php
try{
    $dbh = new pdo( 'aws-test-db.hibizibi.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com;dbname=test',
                    'root',
                    'password',
                    array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
    die(json_encode(array('outcome' => true)));
}
catch(PDOException $ex){
    die(json_encode(array('outcome' => false, 'message' => 'Unable to connect')));
}
```

I get `{"outcome":false,"message":"Unable to connect"}`. My original code is using [idiorm](http://idiorm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (which uses PDO). The portion that connects with database looks like below:

```
# configure ORM
ORM::configure('mysql:host='.DB_SERVER.';dbname='.DB_NAME);
ORM::configure('username', DB_SERVER_USERNAME);
ORM::configure('password', DB_SERVER_PASSWORD);
```

From the above I get the below error trace:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2005] Unknown MySQL server host 'aws-test-db.hibizibi.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:3306' (11)
#0 /var/www/html/main/admin/applications/vendors/idiorm/idiorm.php(255): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=aws-...', 'root', 'password', NULL)
#1 /var/www/html/main/admin/applications/vendors/idiorm/idiorm.php(237): ORM::_setup_db('default')
```

*UPDATE*

I updated my test code to try connecting using mysql extension and it worked with mysql but not PDO

```
<?php 

$servername = "aws-test-db.hizibizi.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com"; 
$username = "root"; 
$password = "password"; 
$dbname='test'; 


try{ 
    $dbh = new pdo(
        'mysql:'.$servername.';dbname='.$dbname.';',
        $username,
        $password,
        array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)
    );

    die(json_encode(array('outcome' => true))); 
} catch(PDOException $ex) { 
    echo json_encode(array('outcome' => false, 'message' => $ex->getMessage()))."\n"; 
} 

// Create connection 
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password); 

// Check connection 
if (!$conn) { 
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error()); 
} 
echo "Connected successfully\n";
```

Now, I am getting `{"outcome":false,"message":"SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '\/var\/lib\/mysql\/mysql.sock' (2)"}` while trying t connect through PDO. My attempt through mysql is successful. Seems like the problem is specifically with PDO. Is there anything I can check ?

Comment: Are you missing $dbport = $_SERVER['RDS_PORT']; in php code ?

Comment: shouldnt it try 3306 by default?

Comment: Try replacing aws-test-db.hibizibi.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com;dbname=test;port=3306; in dbh and then see if you are able to connect?

Comment: Sorry boss, no luck :( FYI: my security group is wide open

Comment: Are you able to connect normally from that instance to the RDS? Did you test it out?

Comment: yeh through my mysql command line. like this:  mysql -h aws-test-db.hibizibi.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com -u root -p. I mentioned in the description.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120332/discussion-between-user3360140-and-error2007s).

Comment: I had a very similar problem. See the solution I found here: [Connecting to AWS-RDS-via-PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68625458/connecting-to-aws-rds-via-pdo)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a very old question, but I had the exact same issue and wanted to document it here for anyone who finds this later.

**The Problem**

1. You can connect to your database (Amazon RDS) manually from the command line.
2. You can connect to your database via mysqli in PHP.
3. You can **not** connect to your database via PDO in PHP.

**The Solution**

For me, after trying almost everything, I randomly decided to try and create a new database user. This worked and I was now able to connect via PDO.

This prompted me to investigate the issue a little further and I was able to narrow the issue down to a backslash `\` character in my MySQL password.

There seems to be some kind of conflict between ENV Vars (with `\`), PHP and PDO.

Comment: Jesus.... what an awful issue. I just spent two days on this due to a `!` in my password. This really needs to be fixed and/or documented somewhere. In case anyone's wondering: `.` is safe to use.