# Connecting to AWS RDS via PDO

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, pdo

I have been trying to connect my PHP application to a MySQL database on AWS RDS via PDO. I have seen a similar question here: [Unable to connect to AWS RDS through PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38809418/unable-to-connect-to-aws-rds-through-pdo) but this is over 4 years old with no definitive answers.

I have tried this a couple of ways. Firstly, passing the host name as '<my-db-name.eu-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:3306' and secondly passing the port explicitly in the dsn string via

```
$dsn = $dsn = "mysql:host=" . $this->host . ";port=". $this->port . ";dbname=" . $this->name . ";charset=utf8";
```

(commented out below). Neither works!

The code snippet is:

```
      $dsn = null;
      $options = null;
      $this->host = SYSTEM_CONFIG["database"]["host"];
      $this->type = SYSTEM_CONFIG["database"]["type"];
      $this->name = SYSTEM_CONFIG["database"]["name"];
      $this->user = SYSTEM_CONFIG["database"]["user"];
      $this->pass = SYSTEM_CONFIG["database"]["pass"];
      /* New */
      $this->port = SYSTEM_CONFIG["database"]["port"];

      switch ($this->type) {
         case "SQLSRV":
            $dsn = "sqlsrv:Server=" . $this->host . ";Database=" . $this->name;
            $options = [
               PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => false,
               PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
               PDO::SQLSRV_ATTR_FETCHES_NUMERIC_TYPE => true,
               PDO::ATTR_STRINGIFY_FETCHES => false
            ];
            break;
         default:
            $dsn = "mysql:host=" . $this->host . ";dbname=" . $this->name;
            //$dsn = "mysql:host=" . $this->host . ";port=". $this->port . ";dbname=" . $this->name . ";charset=utf8";
            $options = [
               PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => false,
               PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
               PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
               PDO::ATTR_STRINGIFY_FETCHES => false
            ];
      }
      try {
         $this->pdo = new PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->pass, $options);
      } catch (PDOException $e) {
         $this->logError($e);
      } catch (Exception $e) {
         $this->logError($e);
      }
```

One thing that **does** work is to pass the IP address and port as the host name in the form

```
$this->host = "<IP-address>:3306"
```

However, I only found the IP address by pinging the host name and I am not sure if this is static or a dynamic IP address (the latter would be no good in a config file!).

Any help on this would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have got the code working now, although quite frustratingly I never got to the bottom of why it wasn't working in the first place! I suspect it was something to do with not picking up on the port number properly - maybe a typo somewhere that got 'accidently' corrected (rather than deliberately) when I was trying things out. This code now works (just for MySQL):

```
      $dsn = null;
      $options = null;
      $this->host = SYSTEM_CONFIG["database"]["host"];
      $this->type = SYSTEM_CONFIG["database"]["type"];
      $this->name = SYSTEM_CONFIG["database"]["name"];
      $this->user = SYSTEM_CONFIG["database"]["user"];
      $this->pass = SYSTEM_CONFIG["database"]["pass"];
      $this->port = SYSTEM_CONFIG["database"]["port"];

      switch ($this->type) {
         case "SQLSRV":
            // Other untested code...
            break;
         default: 
            $dsn = "mysql:host={$this->host};port={$this->port};dbname={$this->name};charset=utf8";
            $options = [
               PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => false,
               PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
               PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
               PDO::ATTR_STRINGIFY_FETCHES => false
            ];
      }
      try {
         $this->pdo = new PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->pass, $options);
      } catch (PDOException $e) {
         $this->logError($e);
      } catch (Exception $e) {
         $this->logError($e);
      }
```